# Data leaking between different calls of the same custom hook (using useReducer)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm experiencing some odd behaviour with a custom hook that I've written. I use it as a staging ground to update information locally, before the user commits that information and sends it off to the database. This hook is called in 2 different places: when the user is creating an item (a `nugget`), and when a user is editing an item.

Naturally, we want each scenario to have its own state, and to not have data leak between the two. However, this is exactly what happens. In the `EditScreen`, I call the hook, passing it the data that already exists (`nuggetInput`). In the `NewScreen`, I also call the hook, passing in nothing. Strangely, when I go to the `EditScreen`, the hook implementation in `NewScreen` gets updated. Of course, I'd expect these 2 hooks to be isolated from one another.

To test if this was in fact the case, I separated this useStaging hook out into 2 identical hooks: `useNewStaging` and `useEditStaging`. Sure enough, this works and there are no leaks.

Here is the useStaging hook in question (with parts removed for brevity):

`useStaging.js`

```
let initialState = {
  title: null,
  mediaItems: [],
}

const reducer = (state, { type, ...action }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'TITLE_UPDATE':
      return produce(state, (draft) => {
        const { data } = action
        draft.title = data
    })

    default:
      throw new Error('Called reducer without supported type.')
  }
}


export default (nuggetInput) => {
  if (nuggetInput) {
    initialState = merge(initialState, nuggetInput)
}

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)

const updateTitle = (data) => dispatch({ type: 'TITLE_UPDATE', data })

return {
    nuggetStaging: state,
    updateTitle,
  }
}
```

`NewScreen.js`

```
const NewScreen = () => {
  const { nuggetStaging, updateTitle } = useStaging()
}
```

`EditScreen.js`

```
const EditScreen = ({ inputNugget }) => {
  const { nuggetStaging, updateTitle } = useStaging(inputNugget)
}
```

Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: It looks like you're using a hook outside a react component, which certainly could be the cause of strange behavior. Make sure you're following the rules of hooks.

Comment: `NewScreen` and `EditScreen` are indeed both components. Did you have your eye somewhere else? I can't see what you might have been referring to. Thanks!

Comment: `const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)`

Comment: That looks to be the issue. Thanks!